# Why Camera show my object like broken

Tags: camera, faces, error

I don't know exactly what happens, if it was me writing a hotkey without realizing it, I changed something in the configuration, or simply a Blender error. But when I assign the camera to see my object it appears broken.
[image]

[image]

But when I turn to viewport view the object is ok.

[image]

I'm new to Blender and as much as I've tried I can't figure out what's going on
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've managed to set your camera to a non-camera object (which can happen via View -> Cameras -> Set Active Object as Camera, or via the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>) and then deleted the object.  So, the camera is stuck in a really weird position and is clipping faces incorrectly.  On top of that, you've turned on a local camera, also pointing to the same missing camera object.

To recover, open the sidebar with View -> Sidebar (or the <kbd>N</kbd> key).  Select the "View" tab in the sidebar, and uncheck the "Local Camera" checkbox.

Now, **switch to Object Mode,** and in the outlier, select the "Camera" object.  (If you don't switch to object mode first, it won't work.  You need the camera to be the only thing selected in orange, not red, in the outliner, with the "Camera" object displayed in the properties panel below the outliner.)

With the Camera object selected, use View -> Cameras -> Set Active Object as Camera.  This will move to a new camera location where the apple no longer appears.  Now, select the "Item" tab in the sidebar and enter the following numbers into the Transform panel:

```
Location:
X:   1.25
Y:   -3.7
Z:   2.1

Rotation:
X: 90
Y: 0
Z: 0
```

That should move the camera to where you can see your apple again, though it'll be a little small.  Because you've got the camera set to orthographic mode, you won't be able to zoom using the middle mouse scroll wheel.  Instead, in the properties panel in the bottom right, select the camera-shaped icon ("Object Data Properties") and under "Lens", change the Orthographic Scale to 3.

Now it should look more or less like it did before, but the weird distortion should be gone.

Comment: I remember having made these modifications without fully understanding the operation of these parameters that I used.

Answer (score 0):

Or delete the camera and add a new one, worked for me; <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *> Camera*